# Mark a page as visited, and forward to the correct part of the code depending on whether it has been visited or not?

Tags: jquery, userscripts, visited

I'm not even sure how to word the title correctly. I'm looking for a way to set a page as visited when it is loaded, then run a command. Next time I load the webpage, it will be marked as visited, so it will execute another bit of the code.

Example:

```
    (function(){
//Detect if page is visited, and direct it to the correct part of the code

//This is the set of code to run if the page has not been visited, Set page as visited here
   $( "#button" ).click(); 

//Run this if the page has been marked as visited
   setTimeout(function(){
  window.close();
}, 50);

})();
```

Still rather new to Jquery and such, pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to store information across multiple views of a site is with cookies. You could have a cookie that tracks whether or not the page has been visited. Cookies are local to the user's computer, so the effect should be what you're looking for.

Here's a nice little cookie utility:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You could use it to track whether or not the site has been visited, then your code could check its value and execute different code depending on its value.

Comment: That makes sense, but it might take me a bit to understand how to fully implement it. I'm going to read the documentation a little bit, thanks!

Comment: I think you'll be surprised how simple it is. Give it a shot and feel free to come back if you have any more specific questions.